# Cannot record movie using AVCaptureMovieFileoutput

Tags: macos, avfoundation

I trying to record a video and I'm getting the error like

> Cannot record to URL <#file url> because it is not a file URL.

I define the destination url as follows:

```
NSString *Path = [[NSString alloc] init];
Path = @"/Users/me/Documents/My fols/recording_try/newMovie.mov";
NSURL *dest = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[Path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Then after creating the session, input and output objects. I tried recording like this.

```
mMovieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init] ;
[mSession addOutput:mMovieFileOutput];
[mMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:dest recordingDelegate:self];
```

I have started running the session, tried using begin and comitconfiguration, etc. But every time I run I get an error like:

```
[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate:] - Cannot record to URL /Users/me/Documents/My%20fols/recording_try/newMovie.mov because it is not a file URL.
```

I don't know where I'm going wrong... Could someone please help???

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 2):

Just change your NSURL configuration to conform to file URL type

Something like this:

NSURL *dest = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:<#(NSString *)#>]

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
// variable names should start with lower case letters

// also, let's do as much as we can with auto-released objects
// so we don't have to worry about leaking (if we're not using ARC)
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithString: @"/Users/me/Documents/My fols/recording_try"];
NSURL *dest = [NSURL URLWithString:[path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
if(dest == nil)
{
    NSLog( @"does not appear to be a valid NSURL object" );
    return;
}

NSError * error = nil;
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtURL: dest withIntermediateDirectories: YES attributes: nil error: &error] == YES)
{
    dest = [dest URLByAppendingPathComponent: @"newMovie.mov"];

    // now you can create the session plus input and output objects
    // within this block

} else {
    NSLog( @"was not able to create the directory which contains path %@ - error is %@", path, [error localizedDescription] );
}
```

Comment: The observation for the `NSString` is simply wrong. Of course you can set the pointer to a new string. He didn't try to mutate the object, he just re-set the pointer (although the first alloc init was pointless).

Comment: Okay @Alladinian; I'll buy that. I am pretty certain the ability to set a (presumably auto-released) string via "`path = @"...`" was added as a convenience method in the past few years.  The original poster still isn't creating a valid file URL though, which is why I gave him/her the "`createDirectoryAtURL:`" method, plus the (always useful) error checking.

Comment: I agree. I also think that your answer is really good (it's rare to see coders [especially in SO answers] that are willing to go the extra mile, regarding error checking/handling). So +1 for that.

Comment: Thanks Guys... Your suggestions were greatly useful. However, I had to modify a bit...

NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"/Users/me/Documents/My fols/recording_try"];
    //path = [path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *dest = [[NSURL alloc] init];
    dest = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
Trying to initialize the path directly using a string didn't work. However, when I used this it sprung into action...

Thanks a lot guys...